# response codes in audiovisual stimulus presentation

Tags: audio, psychopy

I built an experiment in Builder view Psychopy (v1.82.01) presenting an image only, sound only and image plus sound together. For my analysis, I need a record of whether the stimulus is image, sound and image plus sound. Do the columns in the excel file entitled ‘key_resp_3.keys’, ‘key_resp_4.keys’ and  ‘key_resp_5.keys’ represent the button code the participants press to ‘IMAGES’, ‘SOUNDS’ and ‘IMAGES AND SOUNDS’ respectively? 
Is this correct? I just want to check whether I am interpreting this correctly. 
I would greatly appreciate some help. 
Many thanks!
Georgia
PS I am happy to send the excel file (i can't see where i can attach it)

Comment: i forgot to add the Psychopy tag sorry!

Answer (score 1):

`key_resp_3`, `key_resp_4`, etc refer to the keyboard components with those names in your routines.

So if, for example, `key_resp_3` occurs in the routine where only an image is shown, then yes, that is what the response represents.

But if `key_resp_3` is on a routine that can show different combinations of stimuli, then you would need some other way to indicate what the response represents (e.g. a column in your Excel file which indicates what sort of stimulus is being presented).